# babel-maven-plugin not transpiling spread operator to ES5

Tags: ecmascript-6, babeljs, transpiler

I am using DOJO toolkit and after upgrading to use the closure compiler, I noticed I needed to transpile to ES5 BEFORE the dojo build util does it's job in order to take advantage of newer ES6+ features.

So I am using `babel-maven-plugin` to accomplish this.

Everything is working fine with the exception that the `...spread` operator is not transpiling.

Do I need to download the `@babel/preset-env` package as well to set the `preset` option? or is there an option I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further discovery there is no need to download any preset package.

`babel-standalone` takes in preset options through its API as [defined here](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-standalone#api) and use in the [babel-maven-plugin here](https://github.com/jarslab/babel-maven-plugin/blob/2d2d11ba1075f63777c1f68dfc441ec3eb76553e/src/main/java/com/jarslab/maven/babel/plugin/transpiler/BabelTranspiler.java#L23).

The preset option is not passed to the Babel API like defined in a `.babelrc` config file. It is passed in without the `preset-` prefix. So to get the `@babel/preset-env` preset option you need to simply pass in `env`.

So to round this out, here are the common presets and how you would pass them through to the API:

- `@babel/preset-env` --> `env`
- `@babel/preset-react` --> `react`
- `@babel/preset-flow` --> `flow`
- `@babel/preset-typescript` --> `typescript`

So in order to use `babel-maven-plugin` I need to set up the `pom.xml` as follows:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.jarslab.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>babel-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.6</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>js-transpile</id>
            <phase>process-resources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>babel</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <verbose>true</verbose>                                  
                <babelSrc>./js/babel/babel.min.js</babelSrc>
                <sourceDir>./js</sourceDir>
                <targetDir>./js</targetDir>
                <presets>env</presets>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```